# evaluation of an integral using the arguments from the proof of the argument principle

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Let $0<r<R$, $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ be analytic on the $B(a,R)$ and non-vanishing on $\partial B(a,r)$. Suppose $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are the zeros of $f$ in $B(a,r)$, listed according to multiplicities. Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

How can I show $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{z^k f'(z)}{f(z)} dz={a_1}^k+{a_2}^k+...+{a_n}^k,$$ where $\gamma(t)=re^{it},~t\in[0,2\pi]$, using arguments similar to that of the Argument Principle?

Hope you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can deform the contour to separate arbitrarily-small circles surrounding each each zero once in the counter-clockwise orientation, while preserving the integral. Then if you study each circle separately, note that you are back to the argument principle: since the values in the circle are close, you can use continuity of $z^k$ and essentially replace it by a constant.